# JavaScript Promise inside async/await function resolve final array of responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

I'm quite a newbie in JavaScript and in Promises.
I'm trying to build an array of objects that I get from an API.

To do so, I've build two functions in a file `MyFile.js`.

The first one returns a promise when an axios promise is resolved. It's

```
function get_items (url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let options = {
            baseURL: url,
            method: 'get'
        }
        axios(options)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error.stack)
            })
    })
}
```

The second one looks like this:

```
let output = []
let next_url = 'https://some_url.com/api/data'
async function get_data () {
    try {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (next_url) {
                get_items(next_url)
                    .then(response => {
                        output.push(...response.results)
                        if (response.next) {
                            next_url = response.next
                            console.log('NEXT_URL HERE', next_url)
                            get_data()
                        } else {
                            console.log('else')
                            next_url = false
                            get_data()
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        reject(error.stack)
                    })
            } else {
                console.log('before resolve')
                resolve(output)
            }
        })
        return await promise
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

It's where I'm grinding my teeth.
What I think I understand of this function, is that:

- it's returning the value of a promise (that's what I understand `return await promise` is doing)
- it's a recursive function. So, if there is a next_url, the function continues on. But if there is not, it gets called one last time to go into the `else` part where it resolves the array `output` which contains the results (values not state) of all the promises. At least, when I execute it, and check for my sanity checks with the `console.log` I wrote, it works.

So, `output` is filled with data and that's great.

But, when I call this function from another file `MyOtherFile.js`, like this:

```
final_output = []
MyFile.get_data()
    .then(result => {
        console.log('getting data')
        final_output.push(...result)
    })
```

it never gets into the `then` part. And when I console.log `MyFile.get_data()`, it's a pending promise.

So, what I would like to do, is be able to make `get_data()` wait for all the promises result (without using Promise.all(), to have calls in serie, not in parallel, that would be great for performances, I guess?) and then be able to retrieve that response in the `then` part when calling this function from anywhere else.
Keep in mind that I'm really a newbie in promises and JavaScript in general (I'm more of a Python guy).

Let me know if my question isn't clear enough.
I've been scratching my head for two days now and it feels like I'm running in circle.

Thanks for being an awesome community!

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems. One is that you never `resolve` the initial `Promise` unless the `else` block is entered. Another is that you should *return* the recursive `get_data` call every time, so that it can be properly chained with the initial `Promise`. You may also consider avoiding the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - `get_items` already returns a `Promise`, so there's no need to construct another one (same for the inside of `get_items`, `axios` calls return `Promise`s too).

You might consider a plain `while` loop, reassigning the `next_url` string until it's falsey:

```
function get_items (baseURL) {
  const options = {
    baseURL: url,
    method: 'get'
  }
  // return the axios call, handle errors in the consumer instead:
  return axios(options)
    .then(res => res.data)
}

async function get_data() {
  const output = []
  let next_url = 'https://some_url.com/api/data'
  try {
    while (next_url) {
      const response = await get_items(next_url);
      output.push(...response.results)
      next_url = response.next;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle errors *here*, perhaps
    console.log(e)
  }
  return output;
}
```

Note that `.catch` will result in a `Promise` being converted from a *rejected* `Promise` to a *resolved* one - you don't want to `.catch` everywhere, because that will make it difficult for the caller to detect errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit untested

```
const api_url = 'https://some_url.com/api/data';

get_data(api_url).then((results) => {
  console.log(results);
}).catch((error) => {
   // console.error(error);
});

function get_items (url) {
  const options = {
    baseURL: url,
    method: 'get'
  };

  return axios(options).then((response) => response.data);
}

async function get_data(next_url) {
  const output = [];

  while (next_url) {
    const { results, next } = await get_items(next_url);
    output.push(...results);
    next_url = next;
  }

  return output;
}
```

Basically it makes things a bit neater. I suggest to look at more examples with Promises and the advantage and when to ease await/async. One thing to keep in mind, if you return a Promise, it will follow the entire `then` chain, and it will always return a Promise with a value of the last `then`.. if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to not use async at all and just recursively return a promise:

```
const getItems = (url) =>
  axios({
    baseURL: url,
    method: 'get',
  }).then((response) => response.data);

const getData = (initialUrl) => {
  const recur = (result, nextUrl) =>
    !nextUrl
      ? Promise.resolve(result)
      : getItems(nextUrl).then((data) =>
          recur(result.concat([data.results]), data.next),
        );
  return recur([],initialUrl)
    .catch(e=>Promise.reject(e.stack));//reject with error stack
};
```

As CertainPerformance noted; you don't need to catch at every level, if you want getData to reject with error.stack you only need to catch it once.

However; if you had 100 next urls and 99 of them were fine but only the last one failed would you like to reject in a way that keeps the results so far so you can try again?

If you do then the code could look something like this:

```
const getData = (initialUrl) => {
  const recur = (result, nextUrl) =>
    !nextUrl
      ? Promise.resolve(result)
      : getItems(nextUrl)
        .catch(e=>Promise.reject([e,result]))//reject with error and result so far
        .then((data) =>
          recur(result.concat([data.results]), data.next),
        );
  return recur([],initialUrl);//do not catch here, just let it reject with error and result
};
```